# Permission denied error after most of the files have been created

Tags: python, csv

So I am able to parse through multiple csv/txt files, remove the columns I wanted and saved them in a new file. I now want this to go to a new folder so that they are separate from the original files. I have 40 total original files and when I run my script, it moves 32 of the files over to the new folder, but I get a Permission denied when it starts on file 33. Why would this be happening if it works on so many of the previous files?

```
    import os, sys, csv

    path = ('C://Users//nelsonj//Desktop//Master_Project')
    trimmed_files = ('C://Users//nelsonj//Desktop//Master_Project//Trimmed_Files')

    for filename in os.listdir(path):

        pref_cols = [0,1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,18,20,22,24,26,30,34,36,40]
        with open(filename, "rb") as sitefile:
            with open(os.path.join(trimmed_files, filename.rsplit('.',1)[0] + "_trim.txt"), 'w') as output_file:
                reader = csv.reader(sitefile, delimiter=',')
                writer = csv.writer(output_file)
                for row in reader:
                    new_row = list(row[i] for i in pref_cols)
                    writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: Could you please supply a full traceback and/or the name of the file causing issues? Since on windows, there are file names that aren't allowed to be created (at least the normal way).

Comment: That's the thing, all of the file names are formatted the same way and are all text files. Such as RIC_2009, RIC_2010. It gets stuck going to TRI_2009